# Zooming nested imageviews in iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, imageview, pinchzoom

I want pinch to zoom functionality on an image view so added the imageview on a scrollview.

That works perfectly fine,but the problem is that I have one more imageview inside it.

For understanding the parent imageview is ATM card image and the other one is the bar code image which is added onto the ATM card. Applying zoom on ATM card zooms in and out well but the barcode doesnt zoom in/zoom out.

What is the correct approach to achieve the same

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your view hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code I can't really be too specific. In my own app I did something similar with a UIView called containerView and added a bunch of UIImages and UIButtons to this view, and when I zoom in everything within the UIView zooms. Here is how you would do it specifically with a UIImageView, I tested it and it worked for zooming both images at the same time. You probably weren't adding the barcode UIImageView as a subview of the atm UIImageView. Hope this helps.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageToZoom;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageSubView;

- (viewDidLoad) {

    _imageToZoom = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    _imageToZoom.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourAtmCard.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:_imageToZoom];

    _imageSubView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20)];
    _imageSubView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourBarcode.png"];
    [_imageToZoom addSubview:_imageSubView];

}

//pinch to zoom method
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"zoomed");
    return _imageToZoom;
}
```